# determine if the series converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I go about determining if the following series converge or diverge.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$

where
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
1/n,  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
1/n^2, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: You could suppose it converges; then consider the sum of your series with the, convergent,  series $0-1/2^2+0-1/4^2+\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k-1/2}$$
And noting that the first term of the right side is less than 1
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k-1/2}<S<-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k-1/2}$$
And since both of those series diverge, then $S$ is also divergent.

Answer (score -1):

Since both the odd an even subsequences of the sequence $(a_{n})$ converge to zero, we can conclude that the entire sequence converges to zero.

There is a well-known result on real analysis which says that such series converge.

**Lemma:** *If the sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$, then the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{n}
$$
converges.*

You can find the proof of such fact on any book of Real Analysis. Actually, you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Proof).

Comment: The convergence of $a_n$ must be monotonic.

Comment: the series actually diverge, atleast according to the solution.

Comment: Sorry! I missed the monotonic detail.

Comment: You could try the following. Rewrite
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{-n+1}{n^{2}}.
$$
Assume that it is convergent. Then it is absolutely convergent because all terms have the same sign. By direct comparison, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{-1}{2n}$ must be convergent, which is false.

Comment: how did you rewrite a_n to be (-n+1)/n^2 ?

Comment: Not $a_{n}$, but $a_{n} + a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @LaloVelasco you cant rearrange the therms of a series if the series is not absolutely convergent. Indeed the series diverges.

Comment: But in this case this is not a rearrangement. Let me explain how does it works.
Consider the sequences $A_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}$ and $B_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{2m}a_{n}$. Then, $B_{m}$ is the subsequence of $A_{m}$ consisting of the even terms: $B_{m} = A_{2m}$. Assume that the series of the problem, namely the sequence $A_{m}$, converges. Then $B_{m}$ converges. But $B_{m}$ is precisely 
$$
B_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{-n+1}{n^{2}}.
$$
This means that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-n+1}{n^{2}}$ converges. Continue as in above and we are done.